# Getting specific data from a 3 column wide data table using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have some data in Columns A, B and C. In Column A, I have the identifying numbers. These can be identical for some rows below each other, but not always (meaning that lets say identifying number 1025 can be in only 1 row, or in 10 rows.)Each identifying number will have 1 or more entries in Column B and C. In Column B, there are some 5-digit numbers. These can be the same in each row, or different. Finally, in Column C, There are some short codes.

What I want to get out from these, is some numbers from column B. I want to check If there are any numbers in Column B, which dont have the code 'HL' in Column C, and put them in Column D beside the first entry of 'HL' in Column C. If there are more than one such a number, the I still want to retrieve them into column D, separated with commas.

Some examples:

```
A          B     C
1025001  11001   HL
1025001  11001   Sl
1025001  11002   ZF
1025001  11001   FG
```

In this case, the number '11002' is retrieved from Column B, because it didnt has the Code 'HL' in column C, and put into Column D  into the Row with the first 'HL' entry with the same identifier.

The end result:

```
A          B     C      D
1025001  11001   HL   11002
1025001  11001   Sl
1025001  11002   ZF
1025001  11001   FG
```

Another example with more rows:

```
A          B     C
1025001  11001   HL
1025001  11001   Sl
1025001  11002   ZF
1025001  11001   FG
2659856  26532   TU
2659856  26856   HL
2659856  26856   TU
3598745  34589   HL
3598745  36598   HL
4896523  48596   NK
4896523  49563   HL
4896523  41236   NK
4896523  41659   HL
```

The result:

```
A          B     C      D
1025001  11001   HL   11002
1025001  11001   Sl
1025001  11002   ZF
1025001  11001   FG
2659856  26532   TU
2659856  26856   HL   26532
2659856  26856   TU
3598745  34589   HL
3598745  36598   HL
4896523  48596   NK
4896523  49563   HL   48596, 41236
4896523  41236   NK
4896523  41659   HL
```

For the first identifying number, 1025001, the result of 11002 is put in Column D because it didnt have the code 'HL' in Column C for that identiying number.

For the second, 2659856, the number 26532 put into the second row, because that is the first row with the same identifying number with code 'HL'.

For the third, 3598745, there are no entries, because all rows have the code 'HL'.

For the fourth, 4896523, two entries in the second row, because those 2 numbers dont have the code 'HL', and because the second row is the first entry with 'HL'.

Ive tried to wrote a Sub myself, but honestly I dont know how to even start it. I have written some codes in VBA, but I dont have enough experience for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to throw this solution into the mix just to give a different perspective.  This code is certainly not the most efficient, but what I'm trying to show is HOW to go about building an algorithm.  Basically just start with how you do it in your head.  You put down the rules in the initial explanation of the issue, from there start building.  You know you're going to have to loop through each row.  Next you start building your If/Then comparisons.  You will run into "initial values" problems, meaning what to do with the first run of the loop when there is nothing to compare to.  How do you want to handle that?  Sometimes a simple "if first runthrough then" is the answer, sometimes--as I did here--you can simply pretend it's a loop like any other.  Maybe as you loop through you may encounter other instances where there is nothing to compare to.

Once the code is all built and works (as I have here), then you can go back through and optimize.  Maybe using dictionaries or arrays are better.  Perhaps building a class is worth doing.  It all depends.  But when you are faced with something like this, just start putting down pseudo-code that mimics what you do when evaluating the rules you put down.

Below is the code that works for your problem.  As I said, it's not the most efficient, it's just what I whipped up doing what I just described above.  I hope this helps demonstrate one way to produce an algorithm to code to.

```
<code>
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet 'It's always wise to put your worksheet into a variable for reference. Much faster
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Set it to the active sheet.

Dim ID As String '- To hold col A value
Dim IDCount As Integer '-To track how many of the same ID we have
Dim NewID As Boolean '-To track if we switch to a new ID
Dim Key() As String '-Array needed since we can have more than one HL Key per example 3
Dim KeyCount As Integer '-An index for the Key array
Dim Code As String '-To hold col C value
Dim Results As String '-To store the results for output when we finish the ID section.
Dim Match As Boolean '-To track key matches

Dim rng As Range '-This will be the entire range of the worksheet
'I'm hard setting it here for the example data for ease.
'You will want to code this to be more dynamic, of course
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(14, 4))

Dim Row As Integer, Col As Integer '-I always have Row & Col when working with worksheets.  Habit.
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 'Index variables for looping and array reference

'Initialize veriables before the loop.
IDCount = 0 'Clearly we start our counts at zero
Results = "" 'And clearly we do not want anything in the results to start with.
For Row = 2 To 15
    If ws.Cells(Row, 1) <> ID Then NewID = True ''The very first row will always be a "new" id.
    If NewID Then
        'First output the results if any
        'Find the First HL coded Row
        For i = 0 To IDCount
            'Row is the current row, -IDCount will reference the first ID in the section.
            'This is why we track the IDCount.
            'Here we want to find the first instance of "HL" to put the results into.
            'All we are doing here is incrementing i until we find "HL"
            If ws.Cells(Row - IDCount + i, 3) = "HL" Then Exit For
        Next i
        'Row-IDCount+i will reference the first instance of "HL"
        If Results <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(Row - IDCount + i, 4) = Results 'Store the results here
            Results = ""
        End If
        'Since we are done with the IDCount from the previous section, clear it.
        IDCount = 0 'Setting to 1 because we are already on the first instance of the new ID
        NewID = False: KeyCount = 0
        ID = ws.Cells(Row, 1) 'Store the new ID value
        IDCount = IDCount + 1
        Code = ws.Cells(Row, 3) 'Store the code value
        ReDim Key(1) 'Initialize the array to have 1 element
        If Code = "HL" Then
            Key(KeyCount) = ws.Cells(Row, 2) 'Insert the new Key
        Else 'If Code <> "HL"
            If Results = "" Then
                Results = ws.Cells(Row, 2)
            Else ' Results <> ""
                Results = Results & ", " & ws.Cells(Row, 2)
            End If
        End If 'Code = "HL" or not
    Else 'If NOT NewID
        'Here we have data to compare.
        IDCount = IDCount + 1 'We have and additional row with the same ID
        If ws.Cells(Row, 3) = "HL" Then
            'Add a key to the array
            KeyCount = KeyCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve Key(KeyCount) 'Add an element to the array, keeping everything.
            Key(KeyCount) = ws.Cells(Row, 2)
        Else
            'Must loop through the section to check if non-"HL" cell matches any stored HL keys
            Match = False
            For j = 0 To KeyCount
                If Key(j) = ws.Cells(Row, 2) Then Match = True
            Next j
            If Match = False Then
                If Results = "" Then
                    Results = ws.Cells(Row, 2)
                Else
                    Results = Results & ", " & ws.Cells(Row, 2)
                End If 'Results = "" or not
            End If 'Match is true or false
        End If 'cell = "HL" or not
    End If 'NewID = true or false
Next Row
```

End Sub 'CommandButton1_Click

Comment: Very educational for me, Ive learned much from this. The code seems to be working like I wanted it to.

Comment: I'm happy to help.  It's worth noting that I didn't clean up my code either.  For example, I have a rng as range variable that I had intended to use, but in development ended up not needing it.  This can often happen when coding this way.  Unlike my bad example here, remember to clean the code! :)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim vA, vB, vC, currA, rw As Range, dict As Object, rng As Range, r As Long, s, k
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion   'input data
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1) 'include one empty row below to 
                                             '  ensure the last Id is accounted for
    
    currA = Chr(0) 'or any unlikely value...
    r = 0          'the first "HL" row for a given Id  
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        vA = rw.Cells(1).Value
        vB = rw.Cells(2).Value
        vC = rw.Cells(3).Value
        
        If vA <> currA Then 'Change in ColA - record any previous values
            If Not dict Is Nothing And r > 0 Then
                s = ""
                For Each k In dict.keys
                    'only ColB numbers which had no associated HL
                    If dict(k) Then s = s & IIf(s <> "", ", ", "") & k
                Next k
                ws.Cells(r, 4).Value = s
            End If
            
            currA = vA
            r = 0
            Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        End If
        
        'process the current row
        If r = 0 And vC = "HL" Then r = rw.Row 'record first "HL" row number
        If Not dict.exists(vB) Then
            dict.Add vB, vC <> "HL" 'True/False
        Else
            ' "cancel" ColB number if it has any associated HL
            If dict(vB) = True Then dict(vB) = vC <> "HL"
        End If
        
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Write No Match

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeNoMatch()
    
    ' Constants
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const srcNumberOfColumns As Long = 3
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "D1"
    Const Criteria As String = "HL"
    Const Delimiter As String = ", "
    
    Dim rng As Range
    ' Define Last Cell Range ('rng').
    Set rng = Cells(Rows.Count, Range(srcFirstCell).Column) _
                               .End(xlUp).Offset(, srcNumberOfColumns - 1)
    ' Define Data Range ('rng').
    Set rng = Range(srcFirstCell, rng)
        
    ' Define Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values and their number of occurrences in first column
    ' of Data Array to the Data Dictionary ('dict').
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        dict(Data(i, 1)) = dict(Data(i, 1)) + 1
    Next
    
    ' Declare additional variables for the For Each Next loop.
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim uniSize As Long
    Dim HL As Variant
    Dim hlPos As Variant
    Dim hlVal As Long
    Dim ResultString As String
    ' Define Result Array ('Result').
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Calculate Start Row ('StartRow').
        StartRow = EndRow + 1
        ' Define the number of occurrences ('uniSize') of the current value
        ' in first column of Data Array.
        uniSize = dict(Key)
        ' Resize HL Array ('HL') accordingly.
        ReDim HL(1 To uniSize)
        ' Write values from third column to HL Array.
        For i = 1 To uniSize
            HL(i) = Data(StartRow + i - 1, 3)
        Next i
        ' Calculate the current HL Position ('hlPos').
        hlPos = Application.Match(Criteria, HL, 0)
        If Not IsError(hlPos) Then
        ' hlPos found.
            ' Adjust current HL Position to fit position in Data Array.
            hlPos = StartRow + hlPos - 1
            ' Define current HL Value ('hlVal') from the second column
            ' of Data Array.
            hlVal = Data(hlPos, 2)
            ' Initialize Resulting String ('ResultString').
            ResultString = ""
            ' Calculate End Row ('EndRow').
            EndRow = StartRow + uniSize - 1
            ' Calculate Resulting String.
            For i = StartRow To EndRow
                ' Check if current row is not the HL row.
                If i <> hlPos Then
                    ' Check if current value in second column is different than
                    ' HL Value.
                    If Data(i, 2) <> hlVal Then
                        ' Check if current value in third column is different
                        ' than Criteria.
                        If Data(i, 3) <> Criteria Then
                            ' Write Result String.
                            ResultString = ResultString & Delimiter _
                                         & CStr(Data(i, 2))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' Write Resulting String to Result Array ('Result').
            If ResultString <> "" Then
                Result(hlPos, 1) = Right(ResultString, Len(ResultString) _
                                                         - Len(Delimiter))
            End If
        Else
        ' hlPos not found.
        End If
    Next Key
    
    ' Write values from Result Array to Target Column Range.
    Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Result
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "No-match data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```